# Migrating Lists with Attachments from one list to another list of different site collection in Sharepoint 2013

Tags: list, migration, document-migration

I have a requirement like migrating a list with attachments(Doc Library)  from one site to another site.

- Both the sites are SP2013 Cross Domain Sites.
- Source Site is Regular site(Single Level Authentication) other one is Confidential site(Multi Level Authentication).
- Total List size is almost 3GB along with attachments.

Require OOTB solution for Migrating data between 2 sites.

Answer (score 0):

There's no SharePoint OOTB solution to do this. If you don't want to code, you can look at tools like ShareGate.